# Why net EMF in series connection of cell is sum of individual EMF?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

Suppose we have two resistor and let A,B,C be points across resistors.Va-Vc=Va-Vb+Vb-Vc.Thus pd across the resistor combination can be obtained by simply adding the individual pds across each resistor.But for this we should have a common point(in this case b) for two resistor and this is not found in cells as adjacent cells have opposite polarity and hence different potential so how we can simply add the individual emfs.Please explain.

Edit
If current move from -ve to +ve terminal of a cell certainly work is done but as it goes forward it comes to -ve terminal of adjacent cell and hence work should be obtained.Why PD b/w +ve of one and -ve of adjacent is not counted?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Could you possibly clarify your question with a diagram of sorts?

Comment: Alex is right. To difficult to follow this without a circuit diagram.

Answer (score 1):

The electric potential difference between two points is a measure of how much work is needed to move a unit charge from one point to the other. (The work may be positive or negative.) If you are crossing circuit elements in series, you do work to cross one, and then more work to cross the next.

Comment: If current move from -ve to +ve terminal of a cell certainly work is done but as it goes forward it comes to -ve terminal of adjacent cell and hence work should be obtained.Why PD b/w +ve of one and -ve of adjacent is not counted?

Comment: Work is done on a charge by a battery (or power supply) to increase its potential energy, and work is done by the charge when goes through a circuit element where it looses potential energy.  Potential differences are scaler quantities which add or subtract.  What do you mean “its not counted”?

Comment: I think I finally understand what you are asking.  If you connect two batteries in series, with the + terminal of one battery connected to the – terminal of the other why is there not a potential difference between those two terminals?  If you connect the the two terminals with a short piece of heavy wire there will be no significant voltage drop on that wire.  Keep in mind that the + and – designations on the terminals just indicate the direction in which the battery will pump electrons.  They do not indicate a voltage relative to an external reference point.

Comment: So you mean to say that the -ve terminal of  one battery and + ve terminal  of adjacent would be at  same electric potential?But how can this be as one has negative and other positive potential creating a difference?

Comment: The potential at the terminals of a battery in a circuit depends on your choice of a reference point and the location of the battery in the circuit.   Both terminals may be positive or negative relative to the reference point. (Any measure of potential energy depends on the choice of a reference point.)

Comment: The voltage of a battery determines the potential difference between it terminals.

Comment: What about adjacent terminals of two different cells in series?

Comment: If the terminals are connected together, they are at the same potential relative to any chosen reference point.

Comment: If two identical cells are connected in series + to -, with no other connections and you choose a reference (zero potential) at the open - terminal,  then the potential will be +V where they are connected and +2V at the open +  terminal..   If you choose the reference at the open + terminal then the potential will be -V at the connection and -2V at the open - terminal.  Choose the reference at the connection and the open terminals will be at +V and - V.

Comment: Get a voltmeter which can read + or - voltage differences, and a couple of batteries and try this for yourself.  [A cheap multi-meter (free with a coupon) can be found at Harbor Freight.] [Connect the black wire to your reference point.]

Comment: Harbor Freight also carries a small round LED flashlight.  If you unscrew the rear cap,the battery mount slides out (three AAA's connected in series).  The conductors are accessible to the pointed probes of their meter. Explore the voltages between various conductors and compare the results with the voltages on the batteries when they are removed from the mount. (Note that the flat ends of the batteries mount on the springs.)

Comment: Suppose I take the potential of positive open terminal +V as reference then may I conclude that the -ve terminal of same cell and +ve terminal of next one will be at 0V?

Comment: That's correct, but I am in the habit of choosing the reference point at a position which can comfortably be assigned a potential of zero.